# Chrome Ext - How to import a module into background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have some functions that I need to share with both my options.js file and my background.js file. I created a file called utils.js and I can import that file into the options.js file pretty easy by way of including a script tag in my options.html page.

This seems to work fine, but I can't seem to figure out a way to get the utils.js file imported into my background.js file. I realize that there are many posts about this here on stack but I'm having no luck.

Can I please get some advice on how to achieve this. Thank you!